# Is it ok to sew the sides of my Judo gi?

Tags: judo, gi

My new *gi* trousers have sides with splits to allow the person to get in and out easily. I am too thin for this *gi* but I have to use it as I am very tall. is it ok to sew these sides up so that my *gi* does not fall off or should I just search for a new *gi*?

Also, for any people with good domestic sewing skills, what is the best stitch and thread for sewing patches onto my *gi*, as the material is too thick for my usual needle and thread or sewing machine.

Comment: Just to be sure we're answering the right question, this is for a Judo *gi*, based on the tags? Also, we generally ask for one question in each question. You may want to post your two questions seperately.

Comment: https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/26/whats-the-best-way-to-sew-badges-onto-a-uniform-so-they-dont-come-off?rq=1 might be a useful reference for the second question.

Comment: Do your pants also have the drawstrings? Those don't work well enough to leave the pants as is?

Answer (score 3):

Sewing machines won't work for sewing patches on your *gi*. I use a straight running stitch (basting) starting with the knot coming through the back of the material. That way, your thread stays inside the outer ridge of the patch.

[image: basting stitch example]

Or you can use the overlap stitch (overcast) to keep the patch from curling and pulling away from your *gi* when you wash it.

You can use both [basting and overcast stitches](https://www.creativesewingtips.com/basic-sewing-stitches.html) to make sure the patch stays secure.
[image: overcast stitch example]

You'll need a thick needle and thick thread. Or you could take it to a seamstress and have her do it for you. That can get expensive though.

As far as your trousers falling down, that is a common occurrence for all practitioners wearing a *gi*.

Once you have your trousers on, pull the drawstrings at the sides FIRST. Then tie a double knot with a bow.

Here's a 37 second video deomonstrating how a thin man ties his trousers to make sure they stay up.

[HOW TO TIE YOUR GI PANTS 37 seconds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6fUbJYkzghU&feature=youtu.be)